# Android - Start multiple timers on button press

Tags: android

So I have a button with a onClick method like this:

```
public void myClickHandler(View v){

    }
```

I have multiple checkboxes on one page, and when that button is pressed it will start a timer on all of the checked boxes. Also, most of the timers have different times. Have any ideas on how I can get this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think,you can use one timer,or just one thread.computing and send different broadcasts or the same broadcast with different args,handle and dispatch in the method onReceive;